# No Sound in Ubuntu 18.04 for iMac 21.5"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mac

I am chasing my tail trying to get the audio to work in my Ubuntu 18.04 on my iMac 21.5". I have already installed pulseaudio as well as pavucontrol but both don't seem to fix the problem. I have opened up alsamixer as well as reloading it with no avail either. Also when I open up alsamixer there is only one source for  audio. Can someone please help me with this? I'm trying to transition to having Ubuntu be my primary OS but I can't do that if I don't have sound.